# Can we open solution using AOM in UFT like we open test?

Tags: qtp, solution, hp-uft

I know we open test and run using Create Quicktest.application object . my question is is there anyway to open solution which contain all the test inside directly instead of openning them one by one as individual test?

```
qtApp.open  TestPath ------what we do 
qtApp.open  SolutionPath ---- what I want
```

Comment: Btw, "AOL" is not a common acronym in this context. You probably meant "AOM", "automated object model", right?

Answer (score 0):

**No. There is no "solution" concept in QTP (implying that by "solution", you mean a project definition used as a frame for all artifacts used in a project).**

**QTP test suites are** "JBOT", i.e. **just a bunch of tests**. That a suite´s test share the same associated library settings and/or shared object repositories makes those tests form a common "project", but -- not formally, and thus not technically.

**If what you need is an IDE that allows more than one test to be opened (open for editing) at the same time, look at the "QuickTest Script editor"** (but it´s just a script *editor*, not really an IDE, and it appears to be quite buggy).

**If you can spend the money, check out [TDS](http://patterson-consulting.net/products/test_design_studio)** which appears to be the only third-party QTP IDE commercially available and worth a look. (I am not related to the maker, and I cannot make a detailed recommendation since I don´t know the tool in depth yet, but what I saw looked rather mature, professional, and useful.)